# Cannot start localdb on startup

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, localdb

Do we need to start the default localdb instance manually everytime. How do i start a localdb server automatically.

do we need to start the server every time before connecting from a application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localDB instance should start up when you first try to access the database. After a few minutes of inactivity, the instance will close and only start again when you try to access the database.

There should be no need to "manually" start localDB, although I have noticed sometimes that the application does not automatically start, though this is intermittent and I can find no explanation for it.

**EDIT**

In order to try to start LocalDB when the application first loads, put this in your Program.cs file, in the Main() function:

```
Process.Start("sqllocaldb.exe", "start v11.0");
```

This will attempt to spin-up the localDB exe on application startup.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tags visual-studio and sql, so I guess it's MSSQL Server.

Go to your services (Control panel - Administrative tools) and find item with name "MSSQLSERVER". Under "Startup type" make sure it's "Automatic"

Comment: LocalDB does not run as a service, but as a standalone executable.